# Getting a NullPointerException with setWebViewClient

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm using this code below, and I don't know why I'm getting a NullPointerException when I try to setWebViewClient()

```
    WebView wv = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.wb);

    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.equals("YOURLINK")) {
                //Change fragment
                return false;
            }else{
                return true;
            }
        }
    });
```

My WebView:

```
<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/wb">

</WebView>
```

Comment: Like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090185/nullpointerexception-on-findviewbyid-in-android

Comment: post the code of `onCreate()` method.

Comment: I reviewed the `onCreateView()`, the problem is the variable `view`. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed the `onCreateView()` method, the problem is the variable `view`. I'm was getting from a wrong layout.

```
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
```